# How to preview upcoming invoices using the Zuora SOAP API?

Tags: zuora, zuora-soap

From the Zuora user interface I can preview a subscription using a convenient "Preview" button. I'd like to perform the same action using the Zuora SOAP API so that I can preview what the upcoming invoices and write some tests.

So far, my theory is to create an empty `Amendment` with `PreviewOptions.enablePreviewMode=true` to get the results of the previewed invoice.

Relevant SOAP docs:

- [Amend docs](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/D_SOAP_API/C_SOAP_API_Reference/E_API_Calls/amend_call)
- [InvoiceData docs](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/D_SOAP_API/C_SOAP_API_Reference/G_API_Complex_Types/InvoiceData)

---

This has partially worked, but it has returned **one `InvoiceData` object, but two would be expected**.

```java
public List<InvoiceData> getInvoicePreview(String subscriptionId){

    ID id = new ID();
    id.setID(subscriptionId);

    PreviewOptions previewOptions = new PreviewOptions();
    previewOptions.setEnablePreviewMode(true);
    previewOptions.setPreviewThroughTermEnd(true);

    Calendar forever = new DateTime().plusDays(1000).toCalendar(Locale.getDefault());

    // A null amendment
    Amendment amendment = new Amendment();
    amendment.setName("Draft amendment for preview");
    amendment.setStatus("Draft");
    amendment.setContractEffectiveDate(forever);
    amendment.setSubscriptionId(id);
    amendment.setType("TermsAndConditions");

    AmendOptions amendOptions = new AmendOptions();

    AmendRequest amendRequest = new AmendRequest();
    amendRequest.setAmendments(new Amendment[]{amendment});
    amendRequest.setAmendOptions(amendOptions);
    amendRequest.setPreviewOptions(previewOptions);

    Amend amend = new Amend();
    amend.setRequests(new AmendRequest[]{amendRequest});

    AmendResponse amendResults;


    try {

        ZuoraCredentials creds = credentialProvider.get();
        ZuoraServiceStub stub = new ZuoraServiceStub(creds.zuoraApiEndpoint);
        Login login = new Login();
        login.setUsername(creds.zuoraApiUser);
        login.setPassword(creds.zuoraApiPassword);
        LoginResponse loginResponse = stub.login(login);
        String session = loginResponse.getResult().getSession();
        SessionHeader sessionHeader = new SessionHeader();
        sessionHeader.setSession(session);
        amendResults = stub.amend(amend, sessionHeader);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error executing Zuora API.", e);
    } catch (UnexpectedErrorFault e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error executing Zuora API.", e);
    } catch (LoginFault e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error executing Zuora API.", e);
    }

    AmendResult[] amendResult = amendResults.getResults();

    printOut(amendResult);      

    return new ArrayList<InvoiceData>(Arrays.asList(amendResult[0].getInvoiceDatas()));
}
```

---

Here's what the data looks like from the Zuora UI

[image: Subscription Invoice Preview]

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to achieve something similar myself for a `subscribe()` call and ended up raising a ticket with Zuora. They said that it was not supported but you could achieve the same thing by aggregating the `InvoiceItem` records.

What I have done is manually group them together based on the start of the service period (`ServiceStartDate`) and sum the totals (e.g. `ChargeAmount`, `TaxAmount`). It appears to work out correctly and you can get the total due at the start of each period.

I suspect this will work for amendments in the same way because an `InvoiceData` record is returned in the same was as for `subscribe()`.

**Update**

- We do now use this for amendments and it does work well in the same way as for subscribe calls.
- One problem we have found is that you cannot preview beyond the end of a termed subscription, but we can set the term type to `EVERGREEN` if needed when previewing (even if the subscription is to be `TERMED` when created).